# Next.js 12 Migration and Eslint configuration with Prettier, Airbnb, Jest/react-testing-library

Tags: next.js, eslint, prettier

UPDATE: Finally got the config and dep versions to work. I updated my files below in case someone else is having the same issues.

I'm migrating a large app from Next.js 10 to v12. I had minor babel configuration, so decided to remove that, while also using Next.js's linter `next lint`. We initially used prettier and airbnb eslint plugins. Instead of the `eslint-plugin-airbnb`, I'm using `eslint-plugin-airbnb-base`. The reason being `eslint-config-next` already contains ESLint rules/plugins for `eslint, eslint-plugin-import, eslint-plugin-react, eslint-plugin-react-hooks, and eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`, which is basically `airbnb`

My issue:

1. I have a small .prettierrc.js file, but the rules are not being applied.
   ie: printwidth: 80
2. FIXED: Also getting this error `Error: Definition for rule 'jest/expect-expect' was not found`

I've been going in circles, some eyes or feedback would be greatly appreciated.

**.eslintrc.json**

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  plugins: ['simple-import-sort', 'unused-imports'],
  extends: [
    'next',
    'next/core-web-vitals',
    'plugin:jest/recommended',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [['@', './']],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
    },
  },
  rules: { {.....},
 "overrides: { ... typescript overrides },
```

**jest.config.js**

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({ 
  dir: './'
})

const customConfig = {
  rootDir: './',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test-utils/jest-setup.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customConfig);
```

**prettierrc**

```
module.exports = {
  bracketSpacing: true,
  printWidth: 80,
  singleQuote: true,
  trailingComma: 'es5',
  arrowParens: 'avoid',
};
```

**package.json**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.9.10",
    "@hookform/devtools": "^4.0.1",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.3.1",
    "@swc/core": "^1.3.3",
    "@swc/jest": "^0.2.23",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^8.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^8.0.1",
    "@types/autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.1",
    "@types/cookie": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.8",
    "@types/google.maps": "^3.45.6",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/lodash.throttle": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/mui-datatables": "^3.7.6",
    "@types/qs": "^6.9.6",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-gtm-module": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.1",
    "@types/stripe-v2": "^2.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "cypress": "^8.6.0",
    "eslint": "^8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest-dom": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^5.0.3",
    "execa": "^4.0.3",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-junit": "^12.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.1",
    "pg-promise": "^10.6.2",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
```

.lintstagedrc.js

```
const path = require('path')

const buildEslintCommand = (filenames) =>
  `next lint --fix --file ${filenames
    .map((f) => path.relative(process.cwd(), f))
    .join(' --file ')}`

module.exports = {
  '*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}': [buildEslintCommand],
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to run prettier as part of your linting process, you need [eslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier). I see you have both eslint-plugin-prettier and eslint-config-prettier. They do slightly different things so check their docs and stick to one of them. Personally, I prefer eslint-config-prettier, so I separate the linting from the formatting, but this is a personal choice!
2. You need to install eslint-plugin-jest, then enable it in the `plugins` section of your ESLint config.

If you are happy with Next.js ESLint config, you should check [Vercel Style Guide](https://github.com/vercel/style-guide), which includes sensible defaults for ESLint, prettier and TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking about the config vs the plugin.

Comment: My issue seems to be with the `eslint-config-airbnb` config. I swapped with the `eslint-config-airbnb-base`. But that seems to be where the issues are.